# Form submit function. Get name of submitted form

Tags: jquery

I'm need to loop through form elements and get the input values. I would like to call the function via form action rather than a listener and get the name of the submitted form.

Here is what i have so far.

```
<form action="javascript:add()" name="form1">

<script language="javascript">
function add(){
    console.log(this.name);
}
```

Comment: "I would like to call the function via form action rather than a listener" Is there any particular reason for this? It's definitely not the most elegant or efficient method of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `form` reference to the function using `this` keyword through `onsubmit` event

```
<form onsubmit="javascript:add(this)" name="form1">
```

```
function add(form) {
   console.log(form.name);
}
```

See this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4A9Tq/)**

Comment: Weird. It returns blank.

Comment: @RyanLutz I am sorry. You have to change `action`with `onsubmit` or `this` will be pointing to `window`. my mistake. see demo I added.

Comment: Gotcha. so action points to window. That explains the output of just logging the form element